# What chapter is episode 150 of naruto

Tags: naruto

I want to read the manga of naruto because i want to read more anime than just sit down and watch on my computer so can you help me try to find what chapter is episode 150?

Comment: http://www.narutoforums.com/threads/naruto-naruto-shippuden-filler-list.501381/

Comment: @AkiTanaka i'm not inclined to VTC as Duplicate because while the linked question lists what arc an episode would belong to it doesn't list what chapters those arcs would be in the manga

Comment: @Memor-X just saying, the accepted answer mentions "anime exclusive plots", which implied that they are not covered in the manga.

Comment: @AkiTanaka ahhh sorry I must have missed that sorry and episode 150 of both series appears in there. since I'm on my iPad and the app won't give me the duplicate question already selected I'll have to wait until I get back on top a computer to cast my vote

Answer (score -1):

It's a filler! So it's not covered in manga.